# Can I modify states of an object in a swing worker thread which has existed before the SwingWorker is instantiated?

Tags: swingworker

Pseudo code:

```
final MyClass object = new MyClass();
workWith(object); // which may modify states of object

SwingWorker<MyClass, Object> sw = new SwingWorker<MyClass, Object>() {
       @Override
       public MyClass doInBackground() {
           modify(object);
           return object;
       }
   };
sw.execute();

MyClass object2 = sw.get();
```

At first I thought it should be safe as the SwingWorker is instantiated after the object. However, after I look a little into detail it seems the SwingWorker uses a thread from an existing thread pool, which means the thread might have already existed before the object was created.

**Question:** Is it safe to modify ***object*** as in the pseudo code? If it's not, is there a simple enough way to modify ***object*** in the worker thread and then return it to the main thread?

Or perhaps put in another way: Is it *somehow* guaranteed that all objects created before the SwingWorker is initialized are seen correctly in the worker thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really answer to the question, but I think the object has to be final, otherwise this won't compile.

Comment: Indeed. I'll correct it.

Comment: And regarding the question... the thread may have existed before the instantiation of `object`, but the SwingWorker surely hasn't.

Comment: I've added a new line workWith(object). As far as I know, when a thread is created it's guaranteed to correctly see the states of all objects which existed before that. But in this case, if the thread was created before object was created, it may not see all the modifications that happen in workWith(object) method, right?

Comment: But the SwingWorker is intialized in the same thread as and after calling`workWith(object)`. How could it possibly see the state which was there before it was even initialized?

Comment: I guess it's about the background thread that the SwingWorker uses, not the SwingWorker object itself.